# Change in Electric Flux on Rotating a Circular Ring

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

A Circular ring of radius r made of a non conducting is placed with its axis parallel to a uniform electric field.

The ring is rotated about a diameter through 180 degrees.

Does the Flux increase, decrease or doesn't change?

**My opinion:**

A Circular ring is quantity that is not associated with any area itself( It encloses an area, but it itself has no contribution).

So Flux in any case should be 0.

However on googling I found several answers dealing with area, all varying and I failed to get a correct explanation.

Is it wrong to assume the ring to have no thickness, i.e., no area?

And please answer what the result would have been of the question.

Comment: Do they mean the flux through the ring material, or the flux through the area bounded by the ring? Usually the latter is intended, not the former that you are thinking of.

Comment: Well they just mentioned "Flux of electric field",  so yes I reckon it's what you mean. So proceeding with your comment, the magnitude of Flux decreases, but the actual value may increase or decrease, as initial Flux may be positive or negative. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with the changing electric or magnetic field, problems usually refer to the area enclosed by a ring or a frame.  It is OK to assume that the ring has no thickness.

> Does the Flux increase, decrease or doesn't change?

Flux is defined as a dot product of the area and the field, here it is an electric field: $\Phi =\mathbf E \cdot \mathbf A$, or $\Phi = EA\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the electric field and the area normal.  Since angle $\theta$ changes in time (because the ring rotates), the flux changes periodically as the $\cos\theta$ does:

- decreases for $\theta \in \left(0 + \pi, \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right)$
- increases for $\theta \in \left(\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi, \pi + k\pi\right)$

So it either increases or decreases depends on the phase of rotation.

Comment: yep got it! thanks!